# Connection refused while doing POST request with Vagrant

Tags: laravel, http, post, vagrant

I have an API that works fine with the GET protocol.

I am trying to use POST now, but I am unable to access it.

Using Vagrant SSH or a test site, it gets rejected:

```
vagrant@smyprojectt:~$ curl -X POST -v http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/xml/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused
```

Doing it directly while outside gives me this answer:

```
me@myuser:~$ curl -X POST -v http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/xml/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /api/xml/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Wed, 09 Jan 2019 09:50:46 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
< Location: http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/xml
< Content-Length: 322
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/xml">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 8080</address>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

The rest of the application works fine, including AJAX or forms that use POST, but this petition in particular gets refused.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Each POST/PATCH/PUT/DELETE requests are being verified using a CSRF token. So you either pass the token in your request, or in your `Http/Kernel.php` file comment out the `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,` within the `$middlewareGroups` array in order to test.